# My Chrome extension doesn't do anything... it has a manifest.json, main.css and index.html

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension for the first time. I loaded it onto Chrome extensions with no errors, but my code doesn't seem to do anything. I tried to edit the code and look for errors, but after solving all of them the result was still the same. Try as I might, all that comes up is a little white square, and nothing happens.The point of the extension is to show a cute kitten image as the background for the current page. I will show a snippet on my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Cute Kitten Homepage!",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "This extension shows an adorable kitten from google for the current page",
    "author": "Nina Hodges",
    "content_scripts": [
   {
      "matches":    ["<all_urls>"],
      "css":        ["main.css"]
   }
],
    "action":{
         "default_popup": "index.html",
         "default_title": "Cute Kitten Homepage",
         "default_icons": 
"https://www.petbarn.com.au/media/wysiwyg/featured_foodfinder.gif"
         }
}
```

I also have an index.html and main.css file with it. Here is the main.css file:

```
body#gsr.hp.vasq {
  background-image: url(“https://en.bcdn.biz/Images/2018/6/12/27565ee3-ffc0-4a4d-af63-ce8731b65f26.jpg");
}
div.gb_xe.gb_R.gb_Me.gb_Ee {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Separate index and css files are generally used for extension popups whereas I think you want to create a JavaScript file to make that change to the page; but if you have one I don't see that listed in your manifest's content scripts section, and you haven't included it in your question.

Comment: Replace `“` with a normal quote `"` in your css

Comment: Thanks :) I did replace the “ with ", but still with the same result